# How to fetch array of number in firestore using kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

So this is my code right now but the app still crashes when I run this:

```
db.collection("historyCal").document(idData.toString()).get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        if (document != null) {
            val calin = document.get("calInDay") as List<*>
            calin.forEach {
                Log.d("someTag",calin.toString())
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("noexist", "No such document")
        }
    }
```

I have data that consists of:

1. collection: historyCal
2. document: id user I already put on variable idData
3. fields: callInDay, it's an array consist of a number (2000,2100,2000)

I want to get data from callInDay and print each value with a log:

The error log :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.joshua.testapp, PID: 27966
> kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.collections.List<*>
> at com.joshua.testapp.HistoryActivity$setBarChartValues$1.onSuccess(HistoryActivity.kt:45)
> at com.joshua.testapp.HistoryActivity$setBarChartValues$1.onSuccess(HistoryActivity.kt:18)
> at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

line 45 : val calin = document.get("calInDay") as List<*>
line 18 : class HistoryActivity : AppCompatActivity() {   //i think this is due to line 45

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: no one will understand the problem without error logs. Remember to post them with all your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your POJO class is called "Calin", to get the data under "calInDay" array, please use the following lines of code:

```
db.collection("historyCal").document(idData.toString()).get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
    if (document.exists()) {
        val calin = document.get("calInDay") as? List<Map<String, Calin>>
        calin.forEach {
            Log.d("someTag",calin.toString())
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("noexist", "No such document")
    }
}
```

So when you get the data from the "DocumentSnapshot" object, you can extract that array as a `List<Map<String, Calin>>`. However, if you want to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects, please check the following article on Medium:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

Comment: thanks, but i still get the same error log.. 
now, i change the code into this :

`var calin: List<*>? = document.get("calInDay") as List<*>?
                    calin?.forEach {
                        Log.d("calorie",calin.toString())
                    }`
but i didn't get the data

Comment: Have you also tried `val calin = document.get("calInDay") as? List<Map<String, Calin>>`, as in my updated answer? Does it work this way?

Comment: yeah, but i still get the same error.. perhaps due to the POJO ?, `internal class Calin {var cal: List<String>? = null } `

Comment: No, that list doesn't contain String objects, it contains `Calin` objects. It should be: `data class CalinPojo(var cal: List<Calin>? = null)` and then get `val cal = document.toObject(CalinPojo::class.java).cal;`, as explained in that article. Does it work now?

Comment: In that case, you should follow the error message and add "one primary constructor parameter" in your "CalinPojo" class, right? Does it work now, after adding the constructor?

Comment: it seem the list still null.. not get the data from the firestore

Comment: oh okay i found out how to do it.. it's kinda simple just `val cal = document.get("calInDay") as List<Long>` dont need to make a new class.. thanks so much to help me :)